Looping through files on network folder
With the VBA code, I need to go through some folder and subfolders on a network path, extract the data that I need, paste the data onto a destination sheet and make some
manipulations. This is what I have done so far, but I am having trouble adding in a condition that stops running when the name of the folder (Which is a date in the form yyyymmdd) that it is accessing is not equal to the present month and present year. This code currently just goes through all folders which will take a lot of time to complete, so I want it to stop when it reaches
the folder outside of the current month and year.
At the part "While folder <> "", I've tried adding this:
    While folder <> ""
        If IsDateFormat(folder, dateFormat) Then
            Dim currentYear As String: currentYear = Year(Date)
            Dim currentMonth As String: currentMonth = Format(Month(Date), "00")
        Dim folderYear As String: folderYear = Left(folder, 4)
            Dim folderMonth As String: folderMonth = Mid(folder, 5, 2)
            If folderYear = currentYear And folderMonth = currentMonth Then
                fldrStack.Push folder
            End If
        End If
        folder = Dir()
    Wend

However, the code doesn't even execute. However, the VBA code below is fully functional, but it goes through every folder.
Sub Reporting()
    Dim networkFolder As String: networkFolder = "\\folder1\folder2\"
    Dim folder As String
    Dim subfolder As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim destWb As Workbook 'Destination workbook - this is the workbook where we are pasting our values from the source worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet 'Destination worksheet - this is the sheet within the workbook where we are pasting our values. This is the final worksheet that we need at the end
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet 'Source worksheet - this is where we are extracting the values from
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim folderDate As String
    Dim dateFormat As String: dateFormat = "yyyymmdd"
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim file As String
    Dim dateValue As Variant ' Declare as Variant for For Each loop
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    ' Open the destination workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destWb = Workbooks("endfile.xlsm")
    If destWb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Destination workbook 'endfile.xlsm' is not open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Set the destination sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destSheet = destWb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    If destSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet 'Sheet1' does not exist in the destination workbook.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    destRow = 1
 
    '''Identify all folders
    Dim fldrStack As Object: Set fldrStack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
    
    folder = Dir(networkFolder, vbDirectory)
    
    While folder <> ""
        If IsDateFormat(folder, dateFormat) Then fldrStack.Push folder
        folder = Dir()
    Wend
    '''
    
    '''Loop through the identified folders
    While fldrStack.Count > 0
        folder = fldrStack.Pop()
        
        folderDate = Format(CDate(Left(folder, 4) & "-" & Mid(folder, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(folder, 2)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        subfolder = networkFolder & folder & "\Reporting\Daily_Reports\"
        file = Dir(subfolder & "Summary_Report_" & folder & ".xls")

        If file <> "" Then
            filePath = subfolder & file
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
            Set sourceWs = wb.Sheets(1)

            ' Define the data range
            lastRow = sourceWs.Cells(sourceWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A6:AT" & lastRow)

            ' Apply filters
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Manual"
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=44, Criteria1:="=*Regular*", Operator:=xlAnd

            ' Copy filtered data to destination sheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A7:AT" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
                dataRange.Copy destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2) ' Paste starting from column B to leave column A for dates
                
                ' Add the folder date beside each copied row
                For Each cell In destSheet.Range(destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2), destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    If cell.Value <> "" Then
                        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = folderDate
                    End If
                Next cell

                destRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Wend
    
    '''Tidy Up
    fldrStack.Clear
    Set fldrStack = Nothing
    
    '''Adding new columns to insert the transformed and pasted data
    destSheet.Columns("A").Resize(, 89).Insert
    
    '''Various transformations
    For i = 1 To destRow - 1
        destSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Manual"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value = "Regular"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "0"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "I").Value = "IT"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value = "Normal"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "CB").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "CC").Value = "CS"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "CD").Value = "MATT"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "CL").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "J").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DK").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DJ").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "O").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DN").Value * (-1)
        destSheet.Cells(i, "V").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DO").Value * (-1)
        destSheet.Cells(i, "S").Value = (destSheet.Cells(i, "V").Value / destSheet.Cells(i, "O").Value) * 100
        destSheet.Cells(i, "W").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DG").Value * 100
    Next i
     
End Sub

'Getting the date in the right format
Function IsDateFormat(folderName As String, dateFormat As String) As Boolean
    IsDateFormat = (Len(folderName) = Len(dateFormat)) And IsNumeric(Left(folderName, 4)) And IsNumeric(Mid(folderName, 5, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(folderName, 2))
End Function


How would that look like?

If folder like Format(Date,"yyyymm##") Then fldrStack.Push folder will only process folder values which matche the current year+month

You can use Like here to test whether folder matches the required format and is in the current month and year.
'Collect all subfolders matxching the current year+month
folder = Dir(networkFolder, vbDirectory)
    
While folder <> ""
    If folder Like Format(Date,"yyyymm##") Then fldrStack.Push folder
    folder = Dir()
Wend

